# How do I obtain properties from included types in a query?

Tags: freebase

I'm trying to get the name and official website of wine producers via querying for Freebase wine producer topics: https://www.freebase.com/wine/wine_producer?schema=

However, unlike the "name" property, official_website comes from the included type organization/organization. Freebase's query editor seems a bit clumsy in that it can't recognize included types, so it errs when I try to obtain the official_website of a wine producer - the editor seems to fail to recognize a wine producer as an organization/organization: http://tinyurl.com/kr7m86w

Here's my query:

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/wine/wine_producer",
  "official_website": null,
  "wines": []
}]
```

How do I get the official website URL of a wine producer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be misunderstanding how included types work.  They have no special significance in this context (and MQL doesn't even know about them).

You can abbreviate property names for any properties of /type/object (e.g. id, name, type) and any property belonging to the most recently specified type (e.g. wines), but anything else must be fully qualified.

The `official_website` property belongs to `/common/topic`, not `/organization/organization`, so the query with the fully qualified property name is:

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/wine/wine_producer",
  "/common/topic/official_website": [],
  "wines": []
}]
```

Note also that:

- `official_website` is not unique, so it needs [], not `null`
- this only returns the first 100 wine producers (the default limit)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why every wine producer lacks an official_website with this query? It seems like an odd coincidence. They also seem to all lack headquarters ...